# AngularJS - update value of input box in a dynamic table on button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

After having checked various Stackoverflow resources, it looks like I am still unable to figure out the Angular way of doing this. The HTML table, which has just an Id column and another text column (input box), is dynamically populated via ng-repeat. Then I provide "update" and "delete" functions/buttons for each individual record showing inside input box. 'Delete' function seems OK, on 'delete' button click I just pass the ID to the function as argument. With 'update' click event, I am not sure how to pass the value of the input box to the function as a second argument. Please see the simplified markup and code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="rec in allRecords">
    <td>{{rec.Id}}</td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="update(rec.Id, HERE_TEXT_FROM_SIBLING_INPUT')">Update</button>
        <input type="text" value="{{rec.Name}}">
        <button ng-click="deleteMonitorGroup(rec.Id)">Delete</button>
    </td>
```

And the controller

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function (MyService, $scope) {

MyService.listAllRecords(function (allRecs) {
    $scope.allRecords= allRecs;
});

$scope.update = function (Id, text) {

        MyService.update(Id, text, function () {
           // update record
        });
}

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-model` there on input fields like `ng-model="rec.Name"` which keep  `rec.Name` updated by angular two way binding feature.Then do pass `ng-model`'s `rec.Name` to the updated function **OR** rather just pass `rec` object on function call to make it more simpler.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="rec in allRecords">
    <td>{{rec.Id}}</td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="update(rec)">Update</button>
        <input type="text" ng-model="rec.Name">
        <button ng-click="deleteMonitorGroup(rec.Id)">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and very quick answer, all works fine now!